# RavenDB UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true "Access denied" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb

I'm trying to connect to an embedded `RavenDB` database inside my MVC4 application this way:

```
NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
       ConnectionStringName = ConnectionStringName,
       UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
};

documentStore.Initialize();
```

if I remove `UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true` option it works and I can normally save and read from database! But if specify it to access via Management Studio (localhost:8080) I get an `Access Denied` error in  `documentStore.Initialize()`!

this is the full stack:

```
[HttpListenerException (0x5): Accesso negato]
   System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes() +335
   System.Net.HttpListener.Start() +680
   Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.StartListening() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v2.0\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:336
   Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.InitializeInternal() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v2.0\Raven.Client.Embedded\EmbeddableDocumentStore.cs:210
   Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore.Initialize() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Unstable-v2.0\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentStore.cs:424
   RavenDbTest.Repository.DocumentStoreHolder.get_DocumentStore() in c:\Sviluppo\RavenDbTest\RavenDbTest\RavenDbTest\Repository\DocumentStoreHolder.cs:39
   RavenDbTest.Controllers.RavenController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in c:\Sviluppo\RavenDbTest\RavenDbTest\RavenDbTest\Controllers\RavenController.cs:23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain) +145
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +266
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +202
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +838303
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +825393
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +401
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +785498
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +146
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +166
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12551795
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

I run IIS 7.5, VS2012 as Administrator and I added "Everyone full control" to database folder.

What I can try?

Comment: You should be prompted to grant access to listen to the URL `http://*:8080`, are you not prompted the first time you run?  Or is it possible that another process is listening on port 8080?  I'm guessing it's the latter.  What does the message on the exception say other than "Access denied?"

Comment: No prompt! I tryied also with different ports with no luck!

Comment: Note, you're also using an unstable build, that makes these sort of things "too localized".  Have you tried with a stable build?

Comment: Cannot use stable due to this installation error: "Updating 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.6' to 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' that is compatible with 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.0.8'."

Comment: Try a stable build in a different, empty project (a test project, console project).  It doesn't have to be in your local web project.

Comment: Removed WebApi references and installed Stable! Same error!

Comment: Something else is more than likely taking up the port on your machine.  Have you tried a *different* port?

Comment: See if port 8080 comes up when running this from the command line: `netstat -an|find /i "listening"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting your page on IIS 7.5 on your local machine, then the error you're getting does not depend on whether you run Visual Studio as admin or not.
You need to run your application as Administrator, and you can do it by setting up the user on which application pool your application is configured for is running.

So go to **IIS Manager**, click on the application pool you're using for your app, click **'Advanced Settings...'** and then under **'Process Model'** change the value for 'Identity' property **from default 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' to custom account - Administrator** in your case.

And in general, I'd suggest using EmbeddableDocumentStore for unit tests only (of course run in 'InMemory' mode) and for the applications - configure RavenDB to run as a Windows service.